# Django: Print out all choices for a models.Model class

Tags: python, django, django-models

Im trying to write an algorithm that prints out all choices in a Django model class.

For example: I have a model:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
  field_a = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=[(1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c")]
  field_b = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

The expected output is something like this:

```
"field_a": [(1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c")]
```

Please note the algorithm should ignore field_b because of the missing choices attribute.

Any idea on how this functionality can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [meta options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/meta/) documentation. You can achieve this in the following way:

```
fields = SomeModel._meta.fields()
for field in fields:
    if field.choices:
        print "%s: %s" % (field.name, field.choices)
```